# Posting Data to PHP with Axios

Tags: javascript, php, post, vue.js, axios

I am creating a Vue app where I am posting to PHP using Axios. So what I have is:

```
methods: {
         onSubmit () {
       axios.post('/wp-content/themes/bones/library/jobsResponse.php',{region: Chicago, jobType: Direct Hire}, {headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
       .then(function(response){
         console.log(response)
       })
       .catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
      },

}
```

What that method is doing is when the onSubmit function is ran it will use Axios to POST to a PHP file I created named jobsResponse.php. The data it is posting is 'region: Chicago Region, jobType: Direct Hire'.

Then in that jobsResponse.php PHP file I have:

```
<?php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$region = $_POST['region'];

$jobType = $_POST['jobType'];

echo $region;
echo $jobType;

echo ' this is the posted data content';
?>
```

So that is getting the posted data from Vue using Axios. In Axios I am running a console.log of the response and when I check the console log it shows me the data I posted to the jobsResponse.php
[image]

As you can see in the image above the data from my Vue app was posted to the jobsResponse.php file. So that's all fine and well. What I need to do now is take that data I posted to the jobsResponse.php file and use it in my Vue app.

So currently in my Vue app I am recieving a JSON object using PHP like so:

```
<?php echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12', null, 200, '-dateAdded');?>
```

What I want to do is use the posted data from Axios in that PHP query. So I would need to take that posted data and insert into that PHP in some fashion like:

```
<?php echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true AND customText12:"'.$region.'"','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12'); ?>
```

Adding the $region variable to the PHP query would filter the JSON object to only pull back job posts that have the region of whatever that variable is set to.

So I have the needed data posting, which is good. I'm just not sure how to take that data and use it to generate a new JSON object on the fly, like ajaxing it.

Comment: Are you just looking for [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)? If not, I'm not sure I follow the question.

Comment: @EdCottrell What I really am trying to do is, I am making a Vue app that is pulling a JSON object from getBhQuery. What I want to do is update that with data from user input. So if the user select Chicago Region as an example in a select dropdown I am then wanting to post that data using Axios to the jobsResponse.php file. I'm just looking for a way to take the user input data, post it using Axios, and then update getBhQuery with that data to get a new JSON object with the addition parameters.

Comment: `$_POST` shouldn't really be used like that - I would do something like this instead if you're using PHP 7.x -> `$post = file_get_contents('php://input') ?? $_POST;` `$post = json_decode($post, true);`

Answer (score 3):

Well, `$_POST` is a superglobal, so I wouldn't be overwriting it as they are handled by PHP automatically and best left alone.

Like a comment mentioned, `$post = file_get_contents('php://input') ?? $_POST;` will take the incoming POST request and assign it to the variable `$post`.  Then once you've parsed it: `$post = json_decode($post, true);` this will parse the JSON string into an associated array.

Then get the variables like you mention, `$region` and `$jobType`.

You'd then plug these into your database query, or if you are not making this production and can have fixed data: have a static text file or save a list of jobs to a variable.

```php
// get the incoming POST data
$post = file_get_contents('php://input') ?? $_POST;

// decode the JSON data
$post = json_decode($post, true);

// assign the needed data from the POST object
$region = $post['region'];

$jobType = $post['jobType'];

// define how you want to filter the data
function $sortJobs($job) use ($region, $jobType)
{
  return ($job['region'] == $region) && ($job['type'] == $jobType);
}

// get your jobs data
$jobs = [[ 'type' => 'x', 'region' => 'minneapolis', 'name' => 'developer'], ['type' => 'y', 'region' => 'chicago', 'name' => 'secretary']];

// filter the jobs data
$filteredJobs = array_filter($jobs, "sortJobs");

// return the filtered data
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($filteredJobs);
```